# Similarities between photons and neutrino?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, speed-of-light, neutrinos

Are there any similarities between photons and neutrino?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/84967).

Answer (score 1):

They both have no electromagnetic charge. Also, the photon is massless, and for a long time the neutrino was also thought to be massless.

In the early days of applying supersymmetry to the real world, these similarities motivated [an attempt](http://inspirehep.net/record/91443) to treat the neutrino as the superpartner of the photon. (But this was soon abandoned.)